# Using Azure Automation and creating an X509Certificate2 object from a certificate

Tags: azure, powershell

I am attempting to use a certificate that I have loaded into my automation account to authenticate with Google Sheets API via a service account. This is being done in a PowerShell runbook. The certificate is being retrieved with this command:

```
$cert = (Get-AutomationCertificate -Name 'service-account-cert')
```

Once I have the certificate, I am attempting to create an instance of X509Certificate2 using the following command:

```
New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($cert, $cert_pswd,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable )
```

This script 'works' locally, but fails in azure automation. My hypothesis is the reason for the failure is because 'locally' my cert is represented by a filepath "C:/cert_file_path.pfx". In the sandbox environment, however, Azure seems to be representing the cert itself, which could lead to this error?

How do I declare an X509Certificate2 object in an azure automation sandbox environment using a 'shared credential' from the automation account?

Comment: The certificate in windows is being stored in the Stores with PowerShell runbook.  You need to do same in Azure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code?force_isolation=true

Comment: Gotcha... Is this something that only needs to be done once from a 'cloud' level, or is this done as part of script execution?

Also, looking at the command provided in your reference:

"az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES=<comma-separated-certificate-thumbprints>"

What would the 'app-name' be in the context of an Azure Automation account? Just the name of the automation account itself?

Comment: Most cases I load certificates through a Browser manually in the options. HTTPS (secure) uses TLS for encryption that gets key from certificate.  TLS the server sends a certificate block and client looks up the certificate name in the stores.  The certificate in the server does not need to be loaded unless you want the app to use a specific certificate.  Otherwise, one of the default certificates will be used.

Comment: Hmm. So the certificate I am using here is being used to provide a PowerShell runbook access to the Google API. I am not deploying this as part of an existing app or web page. Not sure if that affects the solution?

Comment: A generic certificate that is used with TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 is very secure.  Using a custom certificate give another level of security.  The same certificate has to be loaded in both client an server.  If you go into your browser setting you will see you already have trusted root certificates as well as personnel certificates.  You do not need add additional certificates in most cases.